# Можно ли преобразовать несколько Java-файлов в один apk?

Tags: java, android, apk, app

У меня есть 2 java-файла и папка с картинками. Могу ли я преобразовать их в один apk-файл? И если да, то как это сделать? И как вообще java-файлы преобразовывать в apk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Можно.
2. Выберите в Android Studio пункт меню «Build → Build Bundle(s)/APK(s) → APK(s)»

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!